# Aurelia: export static files into version subfolder

Tags: gulp, aurelia, browser-cache, jspm

We are using the combination of the following tools/libraries: `Aurelia`, `JSPM`, `gulp`, `aurelia-i18n`. Gulp tasks are similar to ones in Aurelia's `skeleton-navigation` [repository](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-typescript/build).

Before deploying to production, we run `export` command, which creates approximately the following file structure:

```
/dist/app-build-hash1.js (versioned app bundle)
/dist/libraries-hash2.js (versioned library bundle)
/jspm_packages/... (non bundable dependencies are here)
/locales/... (i18n files)
/styles/... (css files)
/config.js
/index.html
```

The problem is that static folders like `locales` and `styles` are cached between different application versions. So, users report missing translations and broken styles immediately after deployment.

Of course, we can reduce caching level of those static files, but that is not desirable.

Another possible solution would be to

- Put static files into a hash-based/versioned subfolder
- Modify `config.js` to route JSPM loader to that subfolder for all those resources

Is there a simple way to extend our current workflow to achieve that?

Other solutions are also welcome.

Comment: Regarding locales, in aurelia CLI we can bundle our resources within the application. So, we don't have to serve resources as static files, consequently we don't have the caching problem. I don't know if there's a locale bundling solution with systemJS skeleton, but you can try to find something. Regarding the styles I think the easiest solution would be putting them into a hash-based subfolder as you said.

Comment: Is it _just_ those `/locales/` and `/styles/` dir's that you want to be in versioned directories?

Comment: There is a solution for bundling locales for SystemJS. See this https://github.com/aurelia/i18n/blob/master/doc/article/en-US/i18n-with-aurelia.md#using-jspm

Comment: @thebluefox We also have our own `config` and `help` folders too.

Comment: @FabioLuz Bundling is an option, but I'm not sure we should make user download ~20 language bundled files instead of just one based on user preference.

Comment: @Mikhail that's make sense. What you could do is dividing your resource into several resources, and your app into several bundles, each bundle would have its own resource. Then, the user would have to download only  what's necessary. However, this is not as easy as it sounds, I know =/.